# I cannot get an Advanced Custom Field code snippet to work - and ACF support say it should work

Tags: themes, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to get the below action to display on an archive page on my site via Code Snippets:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'test_text', 42);

function test_text() {
    the_field('group_5f7ee777725c8', 42);
}
```

This is a hook for Advanced Custom Fields to display some basic text on an archive page (product_cat), ACF support say that this should work - but I cannot get it to display. ACF support have stressed that I need to look at how I am implementing this code, but I can see nothing wrong with implementing this how I am trying (Code Snippets).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the field named "group_5f7ee777725c8"? And is there a post with ID: 42?

Comment: I don't know Code Snippets: where does it run? Will this hook definitely be in place before it's called? You could e.g. add an error_log or some other echo to the code to verify it is actually called. Can you try editing this into your theme's functions.php temporarily to see if that works instead?

Answer (score 0):

You try to access to an ACF group of fields
`group_5f7ee777725c8` and the function `the_field` need a **field key** (not the **group key**).

You shoud replace `group_5f7ee777725c8` with the **field key** you'll find **inside the group**. So in ACF menu click on the group `group_5f7ee777725c8` and find the **field key**. It should start with `field_XXXXX`